# A rotating, elevating platform driven by drive shafts

Tags: design, gears, machine-design, power-transmission

I have never built anything with gears before, and I find myself needing to do just that. Given that I have very little background, I'm mostly looking to be pointed in the right direction.

### The Task

I need to design and build a rotation stage that can both rotate freely in both directions, while simultaneously being able to be elevated through ~0.5 m. Both motions should be driven independently, and I cannot put a motor in the room the platform will live in. The motors need to be about 5 m away, in a different room, around several corners. So, I figured this sounds like a job for a drive shaft (or maybe belts/chains, although I am trying to avoid as much position uncertainty as possible). The actual power requirement is low --- no more than a few kg on the platform as it's being moved. Pardon the potato drawing.

[image: A rotating, elevating platform]

### The Problem

The problem I keep running into is how do I keep the rotational motion system working as the platform is moved through its full linear range. Doing either alone is straight forward --- bevel gears or a worm for the rotation, or a rack and pinion for the translation. My problem is getting them to be able to do both, without the translation uncoupling the rotation system.

### Help

I can't imagine that this isn't a solved problem, somewhere. I just don't know where to look for the answer. I've put a few days into Googling and, while I am now much more comfortable with the types of gears out there, I haven't found anything that starts to explain how I should proceed with combining elements. Any resources people know that could help, or places to look at similar designs would be very helpful.

Comment: Have a look at a car screw jack or one of those mobile access elevators etc

Comment: what range of rotation is required?

Comment: is mounting a motor on the linear stage (or the rotational stage) out of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your answer is a well-lubricated splined shaft. The splined shaft is the translation shaft, while the rotation is a matching internally-splined gear being turned by the rotation input.

The translation input as a rack and pinion will apply the vertical force from below the translation shaft, with an appropriate surface to mate with lubrication or a bearing.

Created via Tinkercad and a combination of graphic software packages to create the gearing portion:

[image: mockup of lift and rotate]